# Justify text inside PdfPTable cell using iText XMLWorker

Tags: java, alignment, itext, xmlworker, text-justify

I am trying to justify the text inside a `PdfPTable` cell with the following code:

```
                    PdfPTable pTable = new PdfPTable(1);
                    pTable.setWidthPercentage(98f);
                    pTable.setSpacingBefore(10f);
                    pTable.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);

                    String content=getContent();

                    list =XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(content);
                    for (Element element : list) {
                        cell = new PdfPCell();
                        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);
                        cell.setVerticalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);
                        cell.setNoWrap(false);
                        cell.setBorderWidth(0);
                        cell.addElement(element);
                        pTable.addCell(cell);
                    }
                    pTable.setSplitLate(false);
                    paragraph.add(pTable);
```

But the text is left aligned. I was successful using a `Paragraph` object instead of a table, but I need to display text in a table.

Answer (score 2):

.NET, but easily converted to Java...

Since you're parsing `[X]HTML` and using `XMLWorkerHelper`, a simple way to justify the text is to use the [overloaded parseXHtml method](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/XMLWorkerHelper.html#parseXHtml-com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter-com.itextpdf.text.Document-java.io.InputStream-java.io.InputStream-) and set the `CSS` style yourself. Sample HTML:

```
<html><head>
<title>Test HTML</title>
<style type='text/css'>
td { 
    border:1px solid #eaeaea; 
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: right; 
    font-size: 1.4em; 
}
</style>
</head><body>
<table width='50%'><tr>
<td>
but I can not see justification of text. 
I tried using only paragraph without using table, 
and it does justification but I need to display 
things in table
</td></tr></table>
</body></html>
```

Parsing code:

```
// CSS specificity selector: apply style below without changing existing styles
string css = "tr td { text-align: justify; }";

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
            document, memoryStream
        );
        document.Open();
        using (var htmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
        {
            using (var cssStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css)))
            {
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                    writer, document, htmlStream, cssStream
                );
            }
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(OUTPUT, memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Note that `XMLWorkerHelper` is smart enough to apply the [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) styles correctly when calling `ParseXHtml()`:

1. Maintains specified styles in `<style>`.
2. Changes text alignment from `right` to `justify`.

Output PDF:

[image]